# Create new data frame from summed column values based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I currently have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
census_2
# A tibble: 236,844 x 5
   STATE  RACE CENSUS2010POP POPESTIMATE2012
   <chr> <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>
 1 01        1         37991           37824
 2 01        1         38150           38597
 3 01        1         39738           37653
 4 01        1         39827           38113
 5 01        1         39353           39628
 6 01        1         39520           39821
 7 01        1         39813           39425
 8 01        2         39695           39636
 9 01        2         40012           39957
10 01        2         42073           39856
# … with 236,834 more rows, and 1 more variable:
#   POPESTIMATE2016 <dbl>
```

The State columns are going to be something I want to universally group by. I will have multiple rows representing the same value in the race column. The CENSUS2010POP column is a census population estimate for that particular racial group in that particular state.

So, what I am ultimately wanting to do, is to get a column for each racial group population estimate for the state overall. For example, say in the original dataset, state = 1 & race = 1 refers to a population in State 1 for white constituents. What I want, is to summate the observations in that state for white population estmates and turn that estimate into a column. Then for the third column in the dataset, I'd have a summation of the population estimates in that particular state for non-whites, say it is equivalent to RACE = 2 in the original dataset above. Here is a brief example:

```
STATE  WHITE_CENSUS10POP                                  NONWHITE_CENSUS10POP
1      = summation(nrow where state == 1 & race == 1)     = summation(nrow where state == 1 & race == 2)
2.     = summation(nrow where state == 2 & race == 1)     = summation(nrow where state == 2 & race == 2)
3
4
5
6
...
50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.  A simple option without having other package dependencies (assuming there are only two 'race') is to do a group by on 'STATE' and `summarise` with two columns by subsetting the 'CENSUS2010POP', based on the value of 'race' and get the `sum`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(STATE) %>%
   summarise(WHITE_CENSUS10POP = sum(CENSUS2010POP[race == 1]),
             NONWHITE_CENUS10POP = sum(CENSUS2010POP[race == 2]), 
            .groups = 'drop')
```

---

A more general option is to get the `sum` of 'CENSUS2010POP' grouped by both 'STATE', 'race' and then pivot the 'long' format data to 'wide' with `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(STATE, race) %>%
   summarise(value = sum(CENSUS2010POP), .groups = 'drop') %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = race, values_from = value)
```

Comment: That appears to have summed the same numbers. Here is what the dataset looked like after running that code: # A tibble: 51 x 3
   STATE WHITE_CENSUS10POP NONWHITE_CENSUS10POP
   <chr>             <int>                <int>
 1 01                  774                 3870
 2 02                  774                 3870
 3 04                  774                 3870
 4 05                  774                 3870
 5 06                  774                 3870

# … with 51 more rows

Comment: @DamonC.Roberts It is different, because the `race` is different.  I used `race == 1` and `race == 2`

Comment: But isn't that just summing the values within `RACE`?  I am looking to use the value of `RACE` as a condition.

Comment: @DamonC.Roberts yes, your code description showed `summation(nrow where state == 1 & race == 1)` i.e. number of rows

Comment: @DamonC.Roberts There is a confusion based on your descriptoin.  I updated the code.  Please check if that is what you wanted